# How to convert DB2 9.5 to DB2 10.5 online (Linux)

Tags: db2

How to convert DB2 9.5 to DB2 10.5 online (Linux) ? This can be done with IBM InfoSphere Data Replication? Has anyone done this or have any idea how to do?

Comment: Are saying that you need to perform a version upgrade but can't take an outage (which is required) to do it, so you're looking for other options?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot migrate the database online.

You can use InfoSphere DR or any other replication software for migration with minimal downtime, however, if your application itself does not support transparent connection failover you will still experience a brief outage.

The process in brief would look like so:

- Install DB2 10.5.
- Create a new database in a DB2 10.5 instance, using `db2look`.
- Install and configure replication software.
- Perform a full refresh from the old (V9.5) database to the new one.
- Continue mirroring until the new database catches up to the old one.
- Initiate application failover.
- Stop replication once the application has fully failed over.